# CSS table and table-cell height

Tags: html, css

I am having issue with `height` being ignored when using `display:table` on Firefox.

[image]

on Chrome it looks ok

[image]

Intention was to make it as a table row with 3 elements in it, one of elements is 'misbehaving' on Firefox by taking more space than expected, to figure out which one I have added `height:70px` on all of then but nothing is coming out of this.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nzdufyzp/)

What am I missing why `height` is being ignored?

Comment: The following elements will ignore CSS definitions of `height`: `table`, `tr`, `th` and `td`. It is calculated by the browser depending on the content. Also, you cannot control `overflow` and `max-height` on those elements. (`overflow` cannot occur, these elements will always fully wrap whatever is inside them).

Comment: why your css has so much body class

Comment: when I checked this fiddle on chrome and firefox both are looking same no issues at all. Can you please check once.

Comment: @Amitsingh It's reusing existing design and in many places needs to override existing behavior so tricks are being done like `.legal.bottom-buttons` where 'normal' `.bottom-buttons` gets overwritten.

Comment: Same result here ff et chrome (both last version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are wondering, I managed to solve this by changing

`display : table` and `display : table-row` to good old `display : block` and then all `display : table-cell` with `display : inline-block` then suddenly all the styles started working predictably on Firefox and after few minor changes like adding pixel `width` to buttons so they would not jump down to new line - sorted it all out.